# xacro arg to xacro:property, or math on xacro args?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should it be possible to set a xacro property with a value passed in as an argument?

```
<xacro:property name="length" value=$(arg length_arg)" />
```

Right now I get:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: $(arg chassis_length_arg)
```

I'd like to be able to do math on xacro arguments, but

```
${$(arg length_arg) / 2}
```

also doesn't work so there appears to be no way to do it other than precomputing the right values and passing them in as args.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115221/xacro-arg-to-xacro:property,-or-math-on-xacro-args?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2014-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It just now occurred to me that the solution is to make a xacro macro wrap all the math on the arguments and the call to the macro reference the arg:

```
 <xacro:macro name="foo" params="chassis_length" >
     ... do something with ${chassis_length/2}
 <xacro::macro>

 <xacro:foo chassis_length="$(arg chassis_length)">
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2